# OpenCV Android - trying to make sample application work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to make a basic sample from OpenCV android SDK work (color-blob-detector project).

I have followed all their instructions, downloaded the ADT bundle for windows 7 64 bit, the OpenCV SDK 2.4.9 and finally I imported the samples in my workspace and they appear in my package explorer.

Basically, in my package explorer I opened the `OpenCV Library - 2.4.9` and `OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection` projects.

In the sample project I receive an error regarding the imports from OpenCV particularly

```
The import org.opencv.android cannot be resolved
The import org.opencv.core cannot be resolved
The import org.opencv.imgproc cannot be resolved
```

However, these appear in the `OpenCV Library - 2.4.9` project, but I do not know how to refer to them or how to include them in the sample project. 
I am a beginner at using eclipse, java or android SDK. Am I missing some obvious step?

Also, on the color blob detector project in the `Properties -> Android` section, in the `Library` subsection there is mentioned an undefined reference to `..\..\sdk\java` which I do not know how to solve.

Can you point me out how to solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add openCV SDK lib to your eclipse too which is located in \OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\java.
Add the project located in that folder as Android Application from Existing Code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencv241jar.htm
 download jar file and add to jar in project properties and then ok press it then all problem slove